# GeoJSON data not displaying on Openlayers map in GeoDjango

Tags: geojson, openlayers-2, geodjango

I have the following code.

*models.py*

```
class PFT(models.Model):

    species=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects=models.GeoManager()
    def __str__(self):              
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.species, self.geom.x, self.geom.y)
```

*views.py*

```
def geojson_provinces(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="geodjango",host='localhost',user='postgres', password='postgres', port=5433)
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    res = dict_cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(geom) AS json FROM pft_pft LIMIT 10;")

    points=dict_cur.fetchall()

    json_res  = []
    for row in points:
        json_obj  = row['json']
        json_res.append(json_obj)
        print(json)
    #json = simplejson.dumps(data)
    dict_cur.close()
    return render_to_response('map.html',
                          {'json_res': json_res},
                         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^geojson/$', geojson_provinces, name='geojson_provinces'),
```

Javascript code in *map.html*

```
<script>

    var map = new ol.Map({
       layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
             source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
       ]
       , target: 'map'
       , view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0]
          , zoom: 2
       })
    });

    var vectorSourceJsonp = new ol.source.Vector({
       format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
       , loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {        
          $.ajax({
             url: "{% url 'geojson_provinces' %}"
             , dataType: 'jsonp'
          });
       }
       , strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.createTile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
          maxZoom: 19
       }))
       , projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });
    // Executed when data is loaded by the $.ajax method.
    var loadFeatures = function(response) {
       vectorSourceJsonp.addFeatures(vectorSourceJsonp.readFeatures(response));
    };
    // Vector layer
    var vectorLayerJsonp = new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: vectorSourceJsonp
       , style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
             color: 'green'
             , width: 2
          })
       })
    });
    var mapJsonp = new ol.Map({
       target: 'mapJsonp'
       , renderer: 'canvas'
       , layers: [osmLayer, vectorLayerJsonp]
       , view: new ol.View({
          center: [-75.923853, 45.428736]
          , maxZoom: 19
          , zoom: 11
       })
    });

</script>
```

When I run http://localhost:8000/geojson only map is getting displayed but not the GeoJSON data as points.

Comment: Can you post your geojson?

Comment: my geojson data is ["{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.996944,31.58]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.670778,31.487083]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[77.253,30.651722]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.672944,31.48325]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.669306,31.456861]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.587101,31.451527]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.590461,31.598462]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[76.554306,31.607389]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse your GEOJSON string.
You can do it with the following code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

The `obj` variable contains the parsed GEOJSON.
You can check the validity of your data on http://geojsonlint.com/

Change the following code to parse the response:

```
var loadFeatures = function(response) {
    vectorSourceJsonp.addFeatures(vectorSourceJsonp.readFeatures(response));
};
```

into:

```
var loadFeatures = function(response) {
    vectorSourceJsonp.addFeatures(vectorSourceJsonp.readFeatures(JSON.parse(response)));
};
```

Comment: Please could you let me know in which part of the code I must parse

Comment: I changed accordingly but still data is not getting displayed. In the command line Im getting 'The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated.
 using=using)'

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided by @yellowcap?

Comment: Yes. In that solution m getting geometry as null even though there is geometry in the table

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you any further. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running raw sql querries, you should use the geodjango api that does the work for you. There is a geojson serializer that does exaclty what you want, [see the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/).

views.py

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from myapp.models import PFT

def geojson_provinces(request):
    first10_serialized = serialize(
        'geojson',
        PFT.objects.all()[:10],
        fields=('species', ),
    )
    return render_to_response(
        'map.html',
        {'json_res': first10_serialized},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

This create valid geojson in your view's response. I am not familiar with openlayers so can't tell if you also have some problems in your javascript.

Comment: When I use the above code I'm getting the following result where geometry is null      {"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EP
SG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, properties": {"species": "Pinus roxburghii Sargent"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"species": "Pinus roxburghii Sargent"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"species": "Pinus roxburghii Sargent"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"species": ...

Comment: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py:45: RemovedInDjango110Warning:
 The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated.
  using=using)

Comment: I updated the answer, try removing the `geometry_field` argument. If you dont have data, it could mean that you have rows that don't have a geometry. Try also `PFT.objects.filter(geom__isnull=False)[:10]`. What does `print [dat.geom for dat in PFT.objects.all()[:10]]` return?

Comment: print [dat.geom for dat in PFT.objects.all()[:10]] returns <generator object <genexpr> at 0x04572530>. And my table has rows with geometry

Comment: The print is not very useful like this, the goal was to see the geometries. Could you try `for dat in PFT.objects.all()[:10]: print dat.geom`?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it is printing                                          SRID=4326;POINT (76.9969439999999990 31.5799999999999980)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.6707779999999990 31.4870829999999980)
SRID=4326;POINT (77.2530000000000000 30.6517219999999990)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.6729440000000010 31.4832500000000020)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.6693060000000060 31.4568610000000000)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.5871010000000040 31.4515269999999990)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.5904610000000050 31.5984620000000010)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.5543059999999970 31.6073890000000010)
SRID=4326;POINT (76.5138890000000060 31.6367780000000000)

Comment: The serializer should find the geometry field and use it to serialize, I dont know why you are getting null values in the results.